# How to pass in a parameter to a custom Zend validator?

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine, customvalidator

I am trying to write a validator in Zend framework.

The validator queries the database to check if a particular record exists, this query uses a where clause. The value for the where clause is specified by another field on the form, so how do I pass this value into the validator?

This is how I add my validator:

```
$adgroup_name->addValidator(new Generic_ValidateUniqueAdGroupName() ); break;
```

Within my validator I have:

```
// Query which gets an array of existing ad group names in db
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
->select('a.name')
->from('AdGroup a')
->where('a.name = ?', $value)
->andWhere('a.campaign_id = ?', $campaign_id);      
$adgroup_names_result = $q->fetchOne(array(), Doctrine::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

How do I pass in $campaign_id? I've tried the following and it doesn't work:

```
$adgroup_name->addValidator(new Generic_ValidateUniqueAdGroupName($campaign_id) ); break;
```

Comment: What version of Zend Framework are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The principle is the same as used in "confirm password" validators. You need the value of another element in the form in the field *when the form is submitted*. That's why attempting to instantiate the validator with the campaign_id is not working: the value of `$campaign_id` is not yet set.

When an element calls `isValid()` on its validators, it passes a second parameter called `$context` that is filled with an array of submitted form values. So your `isValid()` method in your validator should look something like this:

```
public function isValid($value, $context = null)
{
    $campaign_id = $context['campaign_id'];
    // Now build your query using $value - from the element to which this 
    // validator is attached - and the $campaign_id provided by the context.
    // And, of course, return true/false as required.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation David. Makes sense, however I have attempted this approach and I'm getting an error when trying to use the $context array; Fatal error: Declaration of Generic_ValidateUniqueAdGroupName::isValid() must be compatible with that of Zend_Validate_Interface::isValid()

Comment: By using public function isValid($value, $context = null) you should get no error since the $context param is optionnal in the definition, so it fits with the interface declaration

Comment: Amending my answer now. Sorry for the omission. @Jeff: Thanks for the assist.

Answer (score 2):

I think to make `new Generic_ValidateUniqueAdGroupName($campaign_id)` work you need to define a constructor for Generic_ValidateUniqueAdGroupName class and a variable called e.g. $_campaign_id. A draft is below:

```
class  Generic_ValidateUniqueAdGroupName extends Zend_Validate_Abstract {

   protected $_campaign_id;

   public function __construct($campaign_id) {
      $this->_campaign_id = $campaign_id;
   }

}
```

With this, you would  access the id in your query as `$this->_campaign_id`.

Comment: Don't forget to call the parent constructor!

Comment: @Denis 'Alpheus' Čahuk. Zend_Validate_Abstract does not have a constructor.

Comment: That is implementation specific and you shouldn't rely on that information.

Comment: @Denis 'Alpheus' Čahuk. How do I call the parent constructor?

Comment: @Sid. Parent constructor of what? Zend_Validate_Abstract does not have a constructor (https://github.com/mridgway/Zend-Framework-1.x-Mirror/blob/1.11.3/library/Zend/Validate/Abstract.php)

Comment: @Marcin, apologies, I got confused. You're right, however it seems like the value I'm trying to pass through to the validator is not being passed through correctly, or I am not calling it correctly; `$this->_account_id` - Its always empty.

Comment: @Sid. Its ok. In the code there are to underscopes (i.e. $this->__campaign_id) instead of one (i.e. $this->_campaign_id). My mistake. Sorry and I'll correct it now.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to supply the `$options` argument:**

Implementation in [Zend_Form_Element](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_Form/Element/Zend_Form_Element.html#addValidator):

```
public function addValidator($validator, $breakChainOnFailure = false, $options = array())
```

**So, you'd do something like this:**

```
$validator = new new Generic_ValidateUniqueAdGroupName();
$adgroup_name
    ->addValidator($validator, false, array('campaign_id' => 1));
```